# Iframe tag not loaded in Web browser control of Windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have developed a windows form application in which I have added a Web Browser control.
In that web browser control I am adding html content like below

```
<iframe src="pageURL.aspx?ref=iframe" allowtransparency="true" height="310px" width="300px" border="0px" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" style="overflow-x:hidden;"/>
```

To assign above content ot web browser I am using following code

```
wbflyout.Navigate("about:blank");
wbflyout.DocumentText = string.Empty;
wbflyout.Document.OpenNew(true);
wbflyout.Document.Write(dynamic HTML Content);
wbflyout.Refresh();
```

I tried assigning this content to Web browsers body as below-

```
wbflyout.Document.Body.InnerHtml = (dynamic HTML Content);
```

when the form loads a blank white screen is shown.

Why is this happening? If I load only simple heading or text dynamically it works prefect.

Comment: I added an answer below, based on the assumption that you're not able to get something to load in the WebBrowser control. Is that assumption correct, if not please be more accurate in your question. I also assume you want to manipulate the HTML, since you want to refresh or add "dynamic HTML context" - so that's the second part of my answer. If again that's not clear, please provide more info on what you're after (e.g.: write out a little textual scenario).

Answer (score 0):

I'll try answering both refreshing and manipulating, since I think that's the info you're after.

**Refreshing**: For refreshing, try using the [DocumentText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property on the WebBrowser control.

> This property is used best when you want to manipulate the contents of
>   an HTML page displayed in the WebBrowser control using string
>   processing tools. You can use this property, for example, to load
>   pages from a database or to analyze pages using regular expressions.
>   When you set this property, the WebBrowser control automatically
>   navigates to the about:blank URL before loading the specified text.
>   This means that the Navigating, Navigated, and DocumentCompleted
>   events occur when you set this property, and the value of the Url
>   property is no longer meaningful.
>   (Source, MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext(v=vs.110).aspx)

e.g.:

```
webBrowser.DocumentText = "<html></html>";
```

where `"<html></html>"` is your dynamic html, or for example your iframe.

**Manipulating HTML**:
Next, if you would want to manipulate the HTML itself and refresh it, then I'd advise you to use an HTML specific library to aid you with manipulating HTML. An example of this is [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/): http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ - also available on [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/) (NuGet AgilityPack Url: https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack). Then after manipulating it you can use that DocumentText property again to load/refresh the HTML.

Comment: webBrowser.DocumentText = "<html></html>"; is not working as I have to write two different HTML contents, when I use DocumentText it overlaps the earlier content. While using Document.Write it doesn't overlap and both contents are shown.

Comment: Then, as I suggested in the second part of my answer, first Manipulate the HTML (and if needed with use of helper html library, such as HTML Agility Pack), then write it back? What is the exact scenario you're going through, can you describe that so we can provide you with a better answer?

Comment: thing is i have some style elements which i apply before applying the actual HTML content. Like 1) wbflyout.Document.Write(style tag) and then 2) wbflyout.Document.Write(dynamic HTML)  so when I use wbflyout.DocumentText it loads only last value set to it. also I am facing this issue only for some machines specifically for laptop users. its working fine on desktop machines with above given code.

Comment: hmm, I see.. Still, I think that preparing the document you're showing upfront would be a good choice/fix for your problem. I don't see any other way at the moment. Maybe someone else comes up with it.